# Finding out whether something has changed on the server

Tags: java, http, server, updates, etag

I'm currently implementing *BE* part(java) that will allow *FE* developers to find out whether some entities that are currently shown on the web page were *updated* or not.

I have several approaches in mind with their pros and cons. 
For instance:

1. Making a cache that contains changes that are made and FE can pull the values from this cache.
2. More standard way with adding etags to entities. However, it adds some additional complexity to the domain.
3. Supporting some dates in requests and getting only the data that were updated after specified date time.

---

Even though I have a pretty simple model(Entity has several sub-entities). I have to track the following scenarios:

1. Entity or sub-entity is updated *(easy with etags)*;
2. Entity or sub-entity is added *(is it possible with etags? Since we are tracking only existing entities with etags)*
3. Entity or sub-entity is deleted *(the same problems as with adding)*

---

The question is, what the best way to handle such a changes-tracking scenario to solve all the scenarios that I have?

Comment: with changes in the entities you mean like a repository or some change in the database which is represented by some entity?

Comment: Yes. Entities can be changed in the data base. I can generate a new etag or put the change info into cache once it's updated.

Comment: why you dont consider the option to use websockets? then everytime a entity is updated, deleted,..you can publish to all subscriber what happened and all FE users will see the change

Comment: Here is the matter of the load and resources. Sockets can't be used in my current architecture.